# How to read AddressSanitizer output logs? C++ - g++ Compiler Abort Error

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, clang

I am creating a string class, so I am allocating memory. I encoutered an abort from the option `AddressSanitizer`. But I am very new at c++ and I have no idea what to do with this. Except for cmd-z till it doesn't throw the error, lol. So how do I read these output logs?

My os is `osx` and I am compiling with

```
g++ tests/string.cpp -o tests/test -O2 -std=c++20 -fsanitize=address -Wall -Wextra
```

**Updated logs with compile options `-Og -g`**

```bash
==43662==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x611000000271 at pc 0x000106546755 bp 0x7ff7b9e10390 sp 0x7ff7b9e0fb50
READ of size 242 at 0x611000000271 thread T0
    #0 0x106546754 in wrap_strlen+0x184 (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x19754)
    #1 0x1060f74c8 in std::__1::char_traits<char>::length(char const*) __string:342
    #2 0x1060f74a4 in std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string<std::nullptr_t>(char const*) string:842
    #3 0x1060f4a08 in std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string<std::nullptr_t>(char const*) string:840
    #4 0x1060f4b7d in cinc::base::string::operator std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >() string.h:656
    #5 0x1060f271e in main string.cpp:153
    #6 0x1150dc51d in start+0x1cd (dyld:x86_64+0x551d)

0x611000000271 is located 0 bytes to the right of 241-byte region [0x611000000180,0x611000000271)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x1065754f0 in wrap_malloc+0xa0 (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x484f0)
    #1 0x1060ee7dc in char* alloc<char>(unsigned long) global.h:31
    #2 0x1060ee80d in strduplc(char*, unsigned long, bool) string.h:36
    #3 0x1060f5f38 in cinc::base::string::operator+(cinc::base::string) string.h:673
    #4 0x1060f2708 in main string.cpp:153
    #5 0x1150dc51d in start+0x1cd (dyld:x86_64+0x551d)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x19754) in wrap_strlen+0x184
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x1c21fffffff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1c2200000000: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x1c2200000010: fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x1c2200000020: fd fd fd fd fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x1c2200000030: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x1c2200000040: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00[01]fa
  0x1c2200000050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x1c2200000060: fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x1c2200000070: fd fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x1c2200000080: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x1c2200000090: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
==43662==ABORTING
zsh: abort      ./tests/test
```

Comment: If you compile with debug symbols it will tell you the line. Otherwise you can use addr2line

Comment: How can i compile with debug symbols?

Comment: Add the `-g` option to the compiler and then run it. You will get line numbers. For debugging it is also often useful to use less aggressive optimization with the `-Og` option instead of `-O2` (but sometimes the bug happens only at the higher optimization level).

Comment: Okay thanks and the `AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow` means out of range on a pointer / array? I updated the logs, especially `-Og` is really nice indeed.

Comment: @user3134709 Yes (or at least access to memory that you are not supposed to access in some way). In this case, since it is happening inside `strlen`, you are probably passing a `char*` which is not null-terminated to some function which expects a null-terminated string.

Comment: It means memory corruption. Attempting to provide a concise, precise definition of memory corruption is like attempting to provide consise, precise definition of a gruesome car crash, every last detail of it.

Comment: Build and debug under Xcode, it reports ASAN errors in a much friendlier way.